# Why would CSS be rendered differently between IDE Tomcat and Production Tomcat?

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat

My question is in the title...

I have a JSP page with a form. On Tomcat bundled with Netbeans IDE the CSS renders the form exactly as intended, however, when I deploy the WAR file to Tomcat on my production web server the CSS on the form Select element is missing and a standard dropdown box is displayed. All of the other form elements are rendered as intended.

I'm using the same web browser to view the form in both scenarios.

Anyone know what might be going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not rendered differently, since CSS its rendered in your browser. Open a Network monitor (Firefox: Ctrl+Shift+Q, IE: F12, ...) and see if your files are loaded correctly.